# Posionar elemento usando referencia de outro elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

posiciona um elemento usando a referencia da posição da div box, o elemento esta  em display none e quando recebe o evento de click ira aparece na tela, entretanto ele deve aparecer abaixo da div box.

```
<h3> Sindico<i class="taskAtiv glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
    </i>
    </h3>
 <div class="box row col-sm-2 box-white">
        <p class="task">Descrição</p>
        <br />
        <p class="task">Descrição</p>
        <br />
        <p class="task">Descrição</p>
        <br />
    </div>
```

**css**

```
  .box {
        width: 200px;
        font: 8px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 9999999999999999;
        top: 54%;
    }
  .task {
            cursor: pointer;
            padding-left: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
```

**Javascript**

```
  $(".taskAtiv ").on("click", function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
            });
```

Comment: você quer que o div apareça debaixo de "sindico"? ou é o contrário?

Comment: sim, abaixo do sindico

Comment: Não entendi. Como é que um elemento irá receber um click se ele está em `display: none`? Tem algo errado na sua pergunta.

Comment: só agora entendi que era pra um elemento ficar sob o outro, no sentido `z-index` da coisa, hahah... deletando minha resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode recuperar a posição e tamanho do elemento de referência e definir a posição do seu elemento a partir da soma deles para que ele fique abaixo.

```
var elementoReferencia = $(".taskAtiv");
var posicao = elementoReferencia.position();

$(".box").css("top", (posicao.top + elementoReferencia.height()));
$(".box").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(".taskAtiv ").on("click", function (e) {
                $(this).toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
                var referenceElement = $(".taskCheckListHeader");
                var positionElement = referenceElement.offset();
                $(".box").css(positionElement);
                $(".box").toggle();

            });
```

solucao baseada na primeira resposta, agradeco desde ja